# xls python сохранение стиля обьединенных ячеек

Tags: python, xls

Здравствуйте, имеется xls(Excel таблица) обьединенные ячейки с определенным стилем(цвет, шрифт и т.д.). Нужно с помощью Python и xlrd,xlwt библиотек перенести эти обьединеные ячейки на несколько строк ниже с сохранением стиля. Нашел способ переноса с сохранением стиля одной ячейки, но мне надо перенести или же применить стиль к обьедененным ячейкам. При обьединении ячеек, стиль затирается на стандартный.
Ниже код перезаписи ячейки с сохранением стиля:

```
def _getOutCell(outSheet, colIndex, rowIndex):
""" HACK: Extract the internal xlwt cell representation. """
#return list
row = outSheet._Worksheet__rows.get(rowIndex)
if not row: return None

cell = row._Row__cells.get(colIndex)
return cell

def setOutCell(outSheet, row, col, value):
""" Change cell value without changing formatting. """
# HACK to retain cell style.
previousCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)

# END HACK, PART I

outSheet.write(row, col, value)

# HACK, PART II
if previousCell:
    newCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
    if newCell:

        newCell.xf_idx = previousCell.xf_idx
# END HACK
```

Код обьединения ячеек:

```
 rb = xlrd.open_workbook(template_name + ".xls", formatting_info=True) 
 outBook = xlutils.copy.copy(rb)
 outSheet = outBook.get_sheet(0) 
 outSheet.write_merge(row1,row2,col1,col2,value)
```

Пробовал обьединять ячейки и потом каждой изменять стиль - стиль напросто не применяется, если сначала разделенным ячейкам применить стиль, а потом обьединить -стиль затирается. Подскажите возможные способы решения данной проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что у Вас не получился вариант "объединить, потом назначить стиль"

Код, выполняющий копирование данных с объединением ячеек и сохранением стиля:

```
import xlrd
from xlutils import copy

def _getOutCell(outSheet, colIndex, rowIndex):
    """ HACK: Extract the internal xlwt cell representation. """
    row = outSheet._Worksheet__rows.get(rowIndex)
    if not row: return None
    cell = row._Row__cells.get(colIndex)
    return cell

def setOutCell(outSheet, row, col, value):
    """ Change cell value without changing formatting. """
    previousCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
    outSheet.write(row+1, col+1, value)
    if previousCell:
        newCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col+1, row+1)
        if newCell:
            newCell.xf_idx = previousCell.xf_idx

def is_merged(sheet, row, col):
    ''' Вернуть диапазон объединенных ячеек, если заданные row/col входят в него'''
    for cell in sheet.merged_cells:
        if row in range(cell[0], cell[1]) or col in range(cell[2], cell[3]):
            return cell

def set_cell_styled_and_merged(outSheet, row1, row2, col1, col2, style, value):
    ''' Объединить ячейки, назначить им стиль '''
    outSheet.write_merge(row1, row2, col1, col2, value)
    newCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col1, row1)
    newCell.xf_idx = style

def copy_data(work_book, sheet_idx, in_row, in_col, out_row, out_col):
    ''' Копировать данные и стиль из ячейки с координатами in_row/in_col в ячейку out_row/out_col '''
    sheet = work_book.sheet_by_index(sheet_idx)
    outBook = copy.copy(work_book)
    outSheet = outBook.get_sheet(sheet_idx) 
    merged = is_merged(sheet, in_row, in_col)
    data = sheet.cell(in_row, in_col).value
    style = _getOutCell(outSheet, in_col, in_row).xf_idx
    if merged:
        out_row_2 = out_row + (merged[1] - merged[0] - 1)
        out_col_2 = out_col + (merged[3] - merged[2] - 1)
        set_cell_styled_and_merged(outSheet, out_row, out_row_2, out_col, out_col_2, style, data)
    else:
        setOutCell(outSheet, out_row, out_col, data)    
    return outBook


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook("style2003.xls", formatting_info=True) 
    outBook = copy_data(rb, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6)      # ячейка [0,1] - составная
    outBook.save('output2003.xls')
```